# How to treat a var as both int and string.

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
def die():
    first = str(randint(1, 6))
    second = str(randint(1, 6))
    total = first + second
    print "You have rolled a " + first + " and a " + second + ", for a total score of " + total + "."
```

Standard die throwing game, but I'm struggling to print the values for individual die as well as the total. Treating as a string for individual, but then sum leads to concatenation rather than actual sum.

Thanks

Comment: `"You have rolled a " + str(first)`

Comment: I suggest you look into [format strings](https://pyformat.info/), and never actually cast the ints to strings in the first place. Much cleaner, generally.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your variables as numbers and let `print` do the formatting:

```
def die():
    first = randint(1, 6)
    second = randint(1, 6)
    total = first + second
    print "You have rolled a", first, "and a", second, ", for a total score of", total, "."
```

Or you could do some *formatting* using `str.format` to have more control over the default inter-parameter spacing in the above:

```
print "You have rolled a {} and a {}, for a \
total score of {}.".format(first, second, total)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to address your problem (and more still!). Firstly, you need to make sure you keep your integers as type `int` when adding them together, and then cast them to a string when you print them out.

You can do this like the below, using the `str()` casting method and `+` concatenation.

```
def die1():
    """Roll and print two dice using concat."""
    first = randint(1, 6) # keep these as integers
    second = randint(1, 6)
    total = first + second # so addition works
    # but now cast to str when printing
    print "You have rolled a " + str(first) + " and a " + str(second) + ", for a total score of " + str(total) + "."
```

But a handier way is to use the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to put placeholders in your string, and then let python cast and format the integer values for you. If you have big numbers with 4 or more digits, an advantage of this would be that you can use a string formatting code like `"my big number: {0:d,}".format(1000000)` to make your string output like `"my big number: 1,000,000"`, which is much more readable.

```
def die2():
    """Roll and print two dice using str.format()."""
    first = randint(1, 6)
    second = randint(1, 6)
    total = first + second
    # or use the str.format() method, which does this for you
    print "You have rolled a {0} and a {1}, for a total score of {3}.".format(first, second, total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting to change the structure of the var. You can either use them as strings and for total use this line:

```
 total = int(first) + int(second)
```

or use them as int and cast them to string in the print by using str(first) and str(second)

Best

Answer (score 0):

`print "You have rolled a " + str(first)`
This would convert the int to a string, hence concatenating it.

Also, you can do 
`total = int(first) + int(second)` to address the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

1. Convert the numbers back to `int` before adding them:

   ```
   def die():
       first = str(randint(1, 6))
       second = str(randint(1, 6))
       total = str(int(first) + int(second))
       print ("You have rolled a " + first + " and a " + second + ", for a total score of " + total + ".")
   ```
2. Convert the numbers into `str` before printing them:

   ```
   def die():
       first = randint(1, 6)
       second = randint(1, 6)
       total = first + second
       print ("You have rolled a " + str(first) + " and a " + str(second) + ", for a total score of " + str(total) + ".")
   ```

Either solution will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

This would also work. Don't convert `first` and `second` to `str` until after you perform sum on them.  Then remember to cast them as `str` in your `print` statement.

```
def die():
    first = randint(1, 6)
    second = randint(1, 6)
    total = str(first + second)
    print ("You have rolled a " + str(first) + " and a " + str(second) + ", for a total score of " + total + ".")
```

Comment: I think he's using Python 2.x

Comment: This won’t fix the problem of concatenation.

Comment: @Ryan Is right. Even if this was Python3, his answer would still fail for trying to concatenate different types.

Comment: interesting @ChristainDean I compiled it in Python3 and it worked for me.

Comment: Did it print the *sum* or the *concatenation* of the two values? Because that’s what the question is about.

Comment: concat the two values as string